# Qt generic error message

Tags: libraries, deployment, qt

This is the error messsage I get.

[image]

I know it's kind of an eye roller, that it's difficult nigh impossible to tell what I may need without the source, but it seems like a deployment problem as people that installed the Qt SDK can run it. Plus, I figured I'd have better luck asking here than with a chinese developer that speaks google-english.

So here's what I've done:

- I installed the MSVC2012.
- I used a program called cffexplorer to see what the exe was looking for. I have the 7 or so .dlls that are at the top of the tree.
- I found a recent (jun 2013) qwindows.dll from elsewhere on my system and put it in ./plugins (I've tried this file in ./, ./plugins, and ./plugins/platforms
- I created a qt.conf with the following data (I determined the format from an existing Qt based app that works)

> ```
> [Paths]
> Plugins = plugins
> ```

Yet, I continue to get this message. Any suggestions on what I might look for to clear this up?

Comment: put the dlls in the ./platforms

Comment: @ratchetfreak thanks. Same message.

Comment: You need the correct platform dll for your version of Qt. If you are using the current qt version 5.2 a dll created in June of 2013 will certainly not work since its from a previous version of Qt.

Comment: Don't use random qwindows.dll's from the internet, that won't work. If it can't be loaded, that's most often a dependency problem. Check with dependencywalker, if the plugin has further dependencies that are not met, e.g. the MSVC runtime. Which compiler are you using to build the application? Is that MSVC 2012 at all?

Comment: the application is already built and "deployed" (so to speak). If the source was made available I'd just deal. Apparently, it wasn't deployed completely or correctly, so i'm trying to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the developer what compiler was used to build the application. Then you will need the right dll (that was built with the same compiler as the application). Also notice that (by default) the documentation says that `qwindows.dll` should be in the `platforms` folder in the same path as your executable, read more [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html#creating-the-application-package). Depending on whether the developer used a Qt built with angle, you may also need: `libEGL.dll` and `libGLESv2.dll`. [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might help you find dependencies that are not there.